# mercury python: [Run] button?

Tags: python, widget, dashboard

I'm new to the [Mercury](https://mljar.com/mercury/) framework that converts a Jupyter Notebook to a dashboard looks great.

The non-widget code runs before the user presses the [Run] button.

Is there some code (an `if/then` block?) that I should add so that the cells in the notebook (converted to dashboard) do not run until the user presses the [Run] button?

Am I thinking about the [Run] button correctly?